# async-await in Office365 API

Tags: c#, async-await, office365

I am relatively new to C# therefore i have somehow problems to understand the async-await logic in context to the office 365 API. I acquire the token when i use the simple AcquireToken() procedure easily but when i use the async way my programm scope is simply gone and i really dont know what to do.

```
public class Testikus
{
    private Uri serviceEndpointUri = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/");
    private string athUrl = "https://outlook.office365.com/";
    private OfcIntCns cnsHlp = new OfcIntCns();

    public async Task doLoadEvents()
    {

        try
        {
            OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(serviceEndpointUri, async () =>
            {

                AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(cnsHlp.Ath);
                ClientCredential cliCred = new ClientCredential("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy=");
                AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(athUrl, cliCred); // From this point my scope is gone ....

                return ar.AccessToken;
            });
            var evt = await client.Me.Calendar.Events.ExecuteAsync(); 
            MessageBox.Show("I MADE IT HERE");

        }catch(Exception e){
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *my scope is gone?*

Comment: AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(athUrl, cliCred); is bein accessed but it never delivers a result and my program continues elsewhere. it doesnt even throw an exception

Comment: How are you calling `doLoadEvents`?

Comment: simply
           Testikus tsts = new Testikus();
            tsts.doLoadEvents();

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint at `return ar.AccessToken;`?

Comment: yes its no reaching the point so my conclusion was i made an error in the client credentials or my authorization url is wrong but since the not-async version is working i am some kind of clueless

Comment: Now i finally somehow catched an InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the Error was not calling Start() and Wait()

```
        Testikus tst = new Testikus();
        Task tsk = new Task(tst.doLoadEvents);
        tsk.Start();
        tsk.Wait();
```

Comment: Where's this code being called from? Are you inside an `async` method here?